# how to pass large json string to web service using [webinvoke]

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a problem passing a large JSON string to a web service from the client side with a jQuery function. When the lenth of the string increases to 1000 characters, the web service throw an exception "Unspecified Network Error". Please let me know how to pass a large JSON value to a web service using [webinvoke].

Can we increase the size of url or whatever to fix this problem?

Comment: You should post your code here. From what little you've said I might guess you need to use a POST request instead of a GET.

Answer (score -1):

You can serialize your Json as object:

page.asp

```
var data1 = {
       IdTest: ('<%= miAspVar %>'),
       fono: telefono,
       etc, etc
};
var strData = YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify(data1)

callService(testLlamada, strData, EstadoLlamada, onError2);

function onError2(result) {
    alert(result);
}

function EstadoLlamada(result) {
...
}
```

Comment: -1: this makes no sense whatsoever. You can't send unserialized JSON over the network in the first place.